# what is FTP Loopback in unix?

Tags: linux

I am writing a shell script where I need to automate FTP loopback. I am not aware of what FTP loopback is and how I can automate to send many files? Here is what I have been given in a document:

```
ftp loopback
username: xxxx
Password : xxxxx
ftp>
cd /tmp
for n files in /tmp
put file1
put file2 etc.
bye
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for invoking ftp is:

```
ftp [-46pinegvd] [host [port]
```

so `loopback` is the name of  system, either specified in your `/etc/hosts` file or provided by DNS.

There is no mention in the `man` page for `ftp` that the `host` name `loopback` would have any special meaning.

Standard `ftp` doesn't allow you to specify the username and/or password to use, for that you could use `expect`, but instead of doing that you should either  install `ncftp` which has `-u` and `-p` options for providing username and password, or, better, use `scp` or `scftp` if `loopback` supports that (as (`nc`)`ftp` is not securely transmitting login information and those two are).

Comment: Yes. loopback is available in /etc/hosts as localhost. But how do I automate in a script, so it takes the username and password from script itself.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should really look into using `scp`/`scftp` instead of `ftp` if possible.